# How to use/create boost::multi_index?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, multikey

Can someone explain to me in detail how to create a multi index map using `boost::multi_index`? I saw many examples online and also the boost page, but I could not understand it. I would want to map class object pointer by multiple int/longs as keys. Can someone please help me with understanding this?

I have a class `X` and multiple properties of the class which are `long long`, `long`, `int`, `int`. I want to store properties `long long`, `long`, `int`, `int` as keys to map to -> <pointer to X>.

I want to be able to look up the pointer given any property. Some of the properties are unique to each object of `X` and some are not unique.

Comment: You want int or long as key? or one int and one long at the same time?

Comment: You need to show what you're stuck with. As given the only possible answer is to link to the many useful online examples. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have a class X and multiple properties of the class which are (long long), (long), (int), (int). I want to store <(long long), (long), (int), (int)> as keys to map to -> <pointer to X>

Comment: Just to be sure: are you aware that multi-map mean that you could have duplicated keys, not that you may have different keys pointing the same object.

Comment: @AdrianMaire I believe the title is just using the wrong word; the body is about boost::multi_index, which would indeed apply here.

Comment: Oops.. I didn't notice.. that's was a typo

Comment: Corrected it now.. thanks @Angew!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[Boost.Multi-index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) offers an extremely customisable interface, at the cost of offering an extremely complex interface, so it's easy to understand why you're stuck.

I'll present a commented example which should match your use case.

First, our data:

```
struct X
{
  long long l; // assume unique
  int i1; // assume unique
  int i2; // assume non-unique
  // plus any ohter data you have in your class X
};
```

Next, we'll prepare one tag for each index which we want the container to have. Tags aren't strictly necessary (indexes can be accessed by their order), but it's more convenient to provide a name for each index:

```
struct IndexByL {};
struct IndexByI1 {};
struct IndexByI2 {};
```

Now, we have what we need to put together the type of the container:

```
using Container = boost::multi_index_container<
  X*, // the data type stored
  boost::multi_index::indexed_by< // list of indexes
    boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<  //hashed index over 'l'
      boost::multi_index::tag<IndexByL>, // give that index a name
      boost::multi_index::member<X, long long, &X::l> // what will be the index's key
    >,
    boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<  //ordered index over 'i1'
      boost::multi_index::tag<IndexByI1>, // give that index a name
      boost::multi_index::member<X, int, &X::i1> // what will be the index's key
    >,
    boost::multi_index::hashed_non_unique<  //hashed non-unique index over 'i2'
      boost::multi_index::tag<IndexByI2>, // give that index a name
      boost::multi_index::member<X, int, &X::i2> // what will be the index's key
    >
  >
>;
```

That's it, we have a container. Next, here's how we can use it:

```
Container c;  // empty container
X x1{...}, x2{...}, x3{...};  // some data

// Insert some elements
auto& indexByL = c.get<IndexByL>(); // here's where index tags (=names) come in handy
indexByL.insert(&x1);
indexByL.insert(&x2);
indexByL.insert(&x3);

// Look up by i1
auto& indexByI1 = c.get<IndexByI1>();
auto itFound = indexByI1.find(42);
if (itFound != indexByI1.end())
{
  X *x = *itFound;
}

// Look up by i2
auto& indexByI2 = c.get<IndexByI2>();
size_t numberOfHundreds = indexByI2.count(100);
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09a5e461d5d8636a)

And now, some prose about how the beast works in general.

You define a multi-index container by specifying the type of objects it will store (`X*` in your case), and one or more indexes which can be used to access the stored objects. Think of indexes as interfaces for accessing the data.

Indexes can be of different kinds:

- Indexes based on ordering by a key (think `std::set` or `std::map`)
- Indexes based on ranking by a key (think the same plus easy access to *n*th element)
- Indexes based on hashing a key (think `std::unordered_set` or `std::unordered_map`)
- Indexes based on accessing in stable order (think `std::list`)
- Indexes based on random access in stable order (think `std::vector`)

The key-based indexes can also be either unique (like `std::map`), or non-unique (like `std::multimap`).

When defining the container, you pass each index you want to have as one template argument to `boost::multi_index::indexed_by`. (In our example above, I added three indexes).

For indexes which do not use a key (stable order & random access), nothing needs to be specified; you just say "I want such an index."

For key-based indexes, you also need to specify how the key is obtained from the data. That's where key extractors come into play. (These are the three uses of `boost::multi_index::member` in the example). Basically, for each index, you provide a recipe (or algorithm) for deriving the key from the data stored in the container. Currently available key extractors are:

- Use the element itself: `identity`
- Use a data member of the element: `member`
- Use a (constant) member function of the element: `[const_]mem_fun`
- Use a global function: `global_fun`
- Combine multiple key extractors into one: `composite_key`

Note that key extractors are able to dereference pointers transparently. That is, if your data element is a pointer to class `C`, you can specify key extractors over class `C` and the dereference will happen automagically. (This property is also used in the example).

This way a container with indexes is defined. To access an index, you call the `get` member function template on the container. You can refer to an index by its sequential number in the list of template arguments of `indexed_by`. For more readable manipulation, you can however introduce a tag for each index (or just some of them). A tag is an arbitrary type (usually an empty structure with a suitable name) which allows you to use that type as template argument for `get` instead of the index's sequential number. (This is also used in the example).

Once you retrieve a reference to an index from the container, you can use it just like the data structure to which the index corresponds (map, hashset, vector, ...). Changes done through that index will affect the entire container.

Comment: Thanks for that! that was very useful. I dont have the properties as a separate structure as you have described. I would have those properties as members of another class from which class X or its parent would derive from. Would that change anything in your answer?

Comment: @Ram No, I meant `X` to be the structure you're using. I'll clarify the answer.

Comment: Thanks  Angew! Just to make myself more clear, I would like the pointer of a class object to be index/mapped by properties of the class which belong to its parent/parent's parent class.

Comment: @Ram Members of a base class are inherited by the derived class, so no problem there. You can always use a `global_fun` key extractor and do arbitrary processing if you find you cannot easily compose the key from other key extractors.

Comment: Can I just use something like this? Would this work?

Comment: `typedef boost::multi_index_container<
  X*,
boost::multi_index::indexed_by<         
boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<         
boost::multi_index::identity<long long>//index by actual value, property of X in parent class     
boost::multi_index::identity<long>, //index by actual value,property of X in parent's parent  class      
boost::multi_index::identity<int>  //index by another property     of X
>,
>,
> X_ind;`
And take care of inserting objects into the created data structure using the pointer to X and the 3 values I intend to index it?

Comment: @Ram Why not just try it? I believe I've given you enough to base your work on. Anyway, I've copy-pasted the code to Coliru to make sure it works; link added to answer.

Comment: Thanks @Agnew, I already am trying it, just wanted to make sure. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ram `identity` is for when the object *itself* is the key. For you, `X` is *not* the key, a property of `X` is. So `identity` is not the correct extractor.